# How to bind your variables to setTimeout in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    setTimeOut(function(){
        console.log(i);
    },2000);
}
```

When I execute this, its printing 10, 10 times instead of 1,2,3....10. How do I fix this

Comment: You have a syntax error. Use `setTimeout` insted of `setTimeOut`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your code like this

```
function print(i){
    console.log(i);
}

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    setTimeout(print.bind(null,i),2000);
}
```